# How to create javafx web view browser with setup custom proxy

Tags: javafx, webview, proxy

I want to make WebView browser with setup custom proxy. how to make this?

Comment: Recent JavaFX versions use the Java jdk http client, so you need to work out how to configure the [proxy for the http client](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.net.http/java/net/http/HttpClient.html) which is used by web view (I don’t know how to do that).

Comment: Likely, you can use [system properties](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/net/doc-files/net-properties.html) to configure the proxy settings. Also setting a [default proxy selector](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/net/ProxySelector.html#setDefault(java.net.ProxySelector)) may work.